# Positioning a label and a horizontal checkboxlist next to each other

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Trying to place a label and a checkboxlist side by side.  In Visual Studio the preview(Design window form) displays the checkboxlist below the label and this is the same when I place the form on our server and run in IE.  Now if I run this from Visual Studio in IE it works.  Unfortunately I need it to work correctly on the server.  I've tried adding display:inline, inline-block, inline-table, flex to the div and float:right to the checkboxlist.
Why the inconsistencies? How do I get these to line up side by side?

```
<div >
        <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="Select"></asp:Label>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem>Roadway</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Resurfacing</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Storm Sewer</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Sidewalk</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Water</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Sewer</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Sewer Outfall</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Bridges/Culverts</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out(guess I needed a fresh start for the day)....referring to my original code I added Position:relative to the main div and position:absolute to the checkboxlist. It aligns correctly in IE when ran from server.  If running in IE from VS it doesn't align...go figure.

Comment: Did you check that cross browser and at different screen sizes? ... Also, as the behavior switched, now working from server, should ring some warning bells that something is wrong.